# OpenSSL symmetric key vs. .NET symmetric key - not matching

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, openssl, cryptography

I'm trying to use OpenSSL to encrypt a string and then pass that simple string to a C# application to decrypt it.  The problem is I can't use the shared private "plaintext" password because the private keys aren't generated the same.  If I use my c# generated key as a -K hex key, then it decrypts just fine.

I feel that the Password isn't converted to a key the same between c# `CryptDeriveKey` and OpenSSL `PKCS#5 padding`.

Again, if I use the hex key from c# over in OpenSSL -K, it encrypts correctly and decrypts correctly.

I've seen examples where people use OpenSSL libraries in C#.  Is .NET `System.Security.Cryptography` not completely compatible with OpenSSL?

```
C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin>echo test|openssl enc -des-ede3 -e -nosalt -md 
sha1 -base64 -pass pass:MyTestKey -iv 0 -p
```

> key=E76B45CFD69213824DC968FCC31E39285BAA8A11DD8395DE
>   encrypted: 3IFZ8w6kLa0=

```
// ** code simplified so its compacted  (wont build)...
var tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
tdes.IV = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
tdes.Mode = "ECB";
tdes.Padding = "PKCS7";
var pdb = new PasswordDeriveBytes("MyTestKey", null);
tdes.Key = pdb.CryptDeriveKey("TripleDES", "SHA1", 192, 0);
```

> key: B5E67ADF58435DBA0D67CDC49410E6BA2004DA2F97432F76
>   encrypted: i+fxaM3/KAg=

Comment: *"I feel that the Password isn't converted to a key the same between c# CryptDeriveKey and OpenSSL PKCS#5 padding..."* - Correct. You need to search Stack Overflow, or get into the man pages and read about `-pass pass:MyTestKey` and [`EVP_BytesToKey`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/EVP_BytesToKey.html). `EVP_BytesToKey` is used extensively in OpenSSL utilities like `enc` and `dec`. Other libraries even duplicate that function for inter-oping with OpenSSL. See, for example, Crypto++ and [OPENSSL_EVP_BytesToKey](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/OPENSSL_EVP_BytesToKey).

Comment: Thanks.  I have seen c# implementations using OpenSSL objects as you noted already, but I was looking for a solution on the OpenSSL side to be compatible with my current c# logic.  Doesn't seem possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`openssl` doesn't use a fancy key derivation function on `pass`, it simply calculates the SHA1 hash of the input.

To do the equivalent in C#, use a SHA1 CSP to [`ComputeHash()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s02tk69a(v=vs.110).aspx) over the key:

```
SHA1CryptoServiceProvider SHA1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
tdes.Key = SHA1.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("MyTestKey"));
```

Comment: So I'm assuming there isn't way to get OpenSSL to calc the same hex I get with my current c# implementation?  I have to use the existing c# code so my only workaround for OpenSSL users is to generate the hex key and have them use that with -K instead of the plaintext passphrase with -k.